# Toning down lamb with mustard powder: universal tool?

Tags: lamb, mustard, marination

Recently I tried the technique of rubbing lamb with mustard powder over night, in order to tone down the "gaminess". The end result was great and tasted nothing like mustard.

Is it a good idea, to use mustard for this reason, as a sort of universal tool, like salt?

Are there parts of the lamb, where this would be unnecessary or even counterproductive? Are there ingredients or recipes, where it would be a bad idea to use the mustard rub?